# Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool site-related news
- the site's twitter account
- the site's blog
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. This question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/557).

Comment: Anybody want to put together an ad for [The League of American Bicyclists](http://www.bikeleague.org/)? One for our blog? Other ideas?

Comment: I'm doing the blog one right now.

Comment: Did the League one as well. Anyone want ads for anything else? I've got a template set up to do this now. How about Adventure Cycling or even non-bike stuff like Freecycle.org? And how about some more bike advocacy stuff?

Comment: How about small businesses that are well-regarded by the community? (I'm thinking about [The Touring Store](http://www.thetouringstore.com/) and [Peter White Cycles](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/).

Comment: Can we get this post featured to encourage users to add more community ads?

Answer (score 12):

[image: @StackBicycles]

Comment: pretty ad, but I can't get behind promoting that bot!

Answer (score 10):

[image: Bicycles community blog]

Comment: Can these be done so the text auto-generates? It'd be nice to have, say, the three most recent blog post titles.

Comment: I updated the ad with recent post titles instead of general topic text. (It's the same ad otherwise.)

Answer (score 3):

[image: The leading UK charity for transport]

Comment: I know it's a bit bland/vague but it's a good site to visit for cyclists of the UK.

Comment: This looks like a good cause. I'd upvote it if the ad made it clear it was about cycling/transportation advocacy in the UK.

Comment: @freiheit: I'm not quite sure what to say and where to put it

Comment: @Ambo100 - How's this? I got the copy from their web site. Please revert  my edit if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: @NeilFein: No, It's just what I was looking for, thanks. I just need to realign those diagonal bars to match.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The League of American Bicyclists]